# DOM Support Or Maybe PHP Version

Tags: php, dom

I keep getting the following error

"Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()"

Is this because I don't have DOM support on or could it be down to my version of PHP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

must be, check your php_info();

you can read about installing php DOM XML support from

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the Installation section of the [DOM XML article in the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxml.installation.php)

> Windows users will enable php_domxml.dll inside of php.ini in order to use these functions. In PHP 4 this DLL resides in the extensions/ directory within the PHP Windows binaries download. A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the building on Windows section. Also, there is one additional DLL that must be made available to your system's PATH in order for this extension to work. In PHP 4 this is in the dlls/ directory. It's name: For PHP <= 4.2.0, it's libxml2.dll. For PHP >= 4.3.0, it's iconv.dll. And as of PHP 5.0.0, iconv is compiled into your Windows PHP binaries by default so no extra DLL is needed.